# Oracle Group with multiple scenarios

Tags: oracle

I have a table where data is as given below

```
ID  IND_ID
1   NULL
1   NULL
1   NULL
2   123
2   NULL
2   NULL
3   234
3   321
3   NULL
```

My requirement is to update this table in such a way that, within a group (grouping will be done based on column ID), if there is value in column IND_ID, same value should be updated to other rows in column IND_ID having null values within that group. If column IND_ID have null value for all the records within that group, then new sequence should be generated. Currently I am writing two sql for this, one for generating the sequence and other for updating.But not sure how to nullify those records within the same ID group having two different IND_ID

Please find the query below

```
    merge into table tgt 
  using (select ID, 
                IND_ID, 
                rid, 
                row_number() over (partition by ID order by IND_ID) rn 
         from   (select ID, 
                        IND_ID, 
                        rowid rid, 
                        max(IND_ID) over (partition by ID) max_b 
                 from   table) 
         where  max_b is null) src 
    on (tgt.rowid = src.rid and src.rn = 1) 
when matched then 
update set tgt.IND_ID = SEQ.nextval;
commit;
merge into table t1
using (select max(IND_ID)IND_ID,ID from table group by
ID)SRC
on (t1.ID=SRC.ID)
when matched then update set t1.IND_ID=SRC.IND_ID;
commit;
```

For max_b is null, I will generate a new sequence. But in the given input record, for ID=3 , we can see two different values for IND_ID.In this case, I need to nullify IND_ID for ID=3 and generate a new sequence.

My expected output is given below

```
ID  IND_ID
1   434
1   434
1   434
2   123
2   123
2   123
3   435
3   435
3   435
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic for generating a new sequence number.  Also, `ID` of 3 has two different values in its group.  In this case, which of the two numbers should be used to fill the `NULL` rows?  In your expected output, you are using neither of these numbers.

Comment: There are two cases, where I need to generate a new sequence number. Case1: For a particular ID group ,if IND_ID is null for all records within that group

Comment: Case 2: For a particular ID group, if there are multiple value for IND_ID, then I need to nullify those IND_ID values  and create a new IND_ID.This is the case with ID value=3

Comment: is there are REAL unique id on each row? what is the name? **UID** (sense you have oversimplified the details in the question too much)

Comment: There are no unique id for this table , that is why I use row id

Answer (score 0):

You may find last_value() or first_value() useful in this context:

```
select 
  t1.*
, first_value(ind_id) over(partition by id) fval
, row_number() over(partition by id order by UUID) rn
from table1 t1
```

To locate id's with no values in ind_id:

```
SELECT id
from table1
group by id
having max(ind_ID) IS NULL
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ad1f/3